# Insert a number after every value in a vector in R

Tags: r

I want to combine vec_1 and vec_2 in such a way that vec_2 is inserted after every value in vec_1

```
vec_1 <- c(1,5,9)

vec_2 <- 9

end_result <- c(1,9,5,9,9,9)
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: c(rbind(vec_1, vec_2))